# Using COUNTIF but not including blanks with other formula

Tags: excel, countif

Firstly, apologies if this is covered somewhere deep within the site, I have looked through a lot of other posts and none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm creating a workbook for a local league I'm involved in and this is the only sticking point I'm coming up against.

In cell J55, I have the formula:

```
=IF(C11=H55, COUNTIF(D11, "="&E11),0)+IF(C19=H55, COUNTIF(D19, "="&E19),0)
```

(I've simplified this to only look at rows 11 & 19 for the purposes of this question)

So what I'm essentially saying is if the team name is equal to the corresponding name in the table, count if the scores for both teams are equal. Basically I'm trying to get the number of games that end in a draw.

So at it's core, my formula is looking for whether 2 cells are equal. This is fine, other than it is counting even if the score cells are blank.

So if you refer to the below image, in J55, I'm getting the returned value of "2". However for the values I've populated in the results (just the scores in the first game) it should be returning a value of "1".

If anybody can help in any way it would be a great help.

[image: Screenshot of doc]

[image: Screenshot of doc 2]

Comment: At first glance I think it's because you're using a `+`.  It's getting 1 because `D11=10` and 1 more because `C19=H55`. break down the formula into smaller sections (ie, each function separate) to make sure they are each doing what you want them to, before adding them together into `IF`'s or a larger formula.

Comment: Regardless, this isn't a programming question .  See the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and also see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site.

Comment: @Ashleedawg not all questions have to be about programming.  Help with formulas is considered acceptable if the formulas are of sufficient complexity.  Problem is what is complex for one is not always complex for another.

Comment: you have a couple of options on how to achieve this.  Since you have multiple criteria for your countif, you probably want to be using `COUNTIFS` instead where you can add a second criteria of `<>""`  Another option is to completely revamp your formula and use a SUMPRODUCT or an array formula.

Comment: Are you aware of the formula auditing feature ("Formulas" menu, "Evaluate Formula" menu item)? This evaluates your formula step by step, so at every step you might see if the result matches your expectations.

Comment: I didn't but I do now, still learning! Thanks Dominique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of Draws this formula which performs array like calculations will count the number of occurences where where the team name in H55 is equal to the team name in column D or F and when the scores in column D and E are equal:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($C$11:$C$21=H55)+($F$11:$F$21=H55))*($D$11:$D$21=$E$11:$E$21)*($D$11:$D$21<>"")*($E$11:$E$21<>""))
```

Copy down as required.

COUNTIFS options

Based on your formula above, adding the checking for not blank cells using COUNTIFS.

```
=IF(C11=H55, COUNTIFS(D11, "="&E11,D11,"<>"&""),0)+IF(C19=H55, COUNTIFS(D19, "="&E19,D19,"<>"&""),0)
```

COUNTIFS is probably the slightly better option as it does not use array calculations.  However for a small data set it wont make a noticeable difference in calculation time for most users.

Comment: Hi Forward Ed.

Thanks a lot for your response! I've pasted the 2 suggestions into my doc and the SUMPRODUCT option works but the COUNTIFS throws an error with the formula. I've gone through it with my limited knowledge and it seems that it should work, is there anything that's been missed off on that one?

Thanks again!

Comment: my mistake  the <> needs to be inside the quotes.  The formula has been updated to place the "<>" in quotes and then attach it to the blank "" with the &.  result is: `"<>"&""`  since you cant really do `"<>""".

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much, you've been a massive help!